# Aerospike clrestore2 fails

Tags: database, nosql, database-backups, aerospike

I have created backup with clbackup2, backup created successfully. But when I try to restore it with clrestore2, it fails with segfault:

```
# /opt/citrusleaf/bin/clrestore2 -d spike -t 1 -u -v

restoring: host 127.0.0.1 port 3000 from directory spike
Aerospike client version 2.1.14
Jun 13 2013 06:42:31 GMT: starting restore: filename: spike/BB97266288BAE6C_00506.clb FILE 0x7f64d80008c0
Jun 13 2013 06:42:32 GMT: expired 1734 : attempted 7256 : [updated 0 not-updated (existed 7256 gen-old 0)]
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to do this at two different Aerospike installations (Community Edition - 2.6.0 and 2.6.7). Each cluster consists of one node. The first one uses SSD storage, the second one uses usual file storage. Server log keeps silence.

What the problem could be connected with? How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with data containing escape characters. E.g. string data containing '\r' or '\n'. Either store those type of data in Blobs or use latest backup tool and use -b option.